# How to return selectively multiple rows from one rows in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There is a DataFrame, "rawDF" and its columns are

```
time     |id1|id2|...|avg_value|max_value|min_value|std_value|range_value|..
10/1/2015|1  |3  |...|0.0      |0.2      |null     |null     |null     | ...
10/2/2015|2  |3  |...|null     |null     |0.3      |0.4      |null     | ...
10/3/2015|3  |5  |...|null      |null     |null     |0.4      |0.5      | ...
```

For each row, I'd like to return multiple rows based on this five "values" (avg, min, max, std, range). But, if the value is null, I'd like to skip.

So, so output should be

```
10/1/2015|1  |3  |...|0.0 
10/1/2015|1  |3  |...|0.2 
10/2/2015|2  |3  |...|0.3
10/2/2015|2  |3  |...|0.4
10/3/2015|3  |5  |...|0.4
10/3/2015|3  |5  |...|0.5
```

I'm not much familiar with Scala, so, I'm struggling with this.

```
val procRDD = rawDF.flatMap( x => for(valInd <-10 to 14) yield {
 if(x.get(valInd) != null) { ...)) }
    } )
```

This code includes  `null` return. 
So, can you give me some idea?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "flatten" here?

Comment: I edited without the term - I might use a wrong term. Anyway, if you see my example, you could understand what I'd like to do.

Comment: Are you sure that "null" isn't read as a string?

Comment: 'null' is printed with rawDF.show(). Actually, it's null not as a string.

Comment: Add some debugging code inside your loop and let it print the value of both valInd and x.get(valInd), then you'll probably figure out the problem.

Comment: It seems working, but after getting procRDD, "procRDD.take(1000).foreach(println)" shows empty rows like "()". I think when if condition is not met, it yields empty row for procRDD.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit strange requirement but as long as you don't need information about the source column and all values are of the same type you can simply `explode` and drop nulls:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, explode}

val toExpand = Seq(
  "avg_value", "max_value", "min_value", "std_value", "range_value"
)

// Collect *_value columns into a single Array and explode
val expanded = df.withColumn("value", explode(array(toExpand.map(col): _*)))

val result = toExpand
  .foldLeft(expanded)((df, c) => df.drop(c)) // Drop obsolete columns
  .na.drop(Seq("value")) // Drop rows with null value
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. If you have better one, let me know.

```
val procRDD = rawDF.flatMap( x => 
  for(valInd <-10 to 14) yield { // valInd represents column number
    if(x.get(valInd) != null) {
       try   { Some( ..) }
       catch { case e: Exception => None}
    }else None 
  })
  .filter({case Some(y) => true; case None=> false})
  .map(_.get)
```

Actually, I was looking for `filter` and `map` and how to put commands inside.